# rasm and ndisasm

Tags: linux, debugging, nasm

I just tried disassembling some shellcode using disasm and I found the following statement in the disassembly.

`00000005  0000              add [bx+si],al`

As the instruction did not particularly make sense in that context, I tried using rasm as follows :-

`rasm -d "0000"` and the output to that was `add [eax], al`. I'm curious about why this happens.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Apparently, rasm assumes 32-bit-mode while ndisasm does not.

```
echo -ne "\x00\x00" | ndisasm -b 32 -
```

should give the same result as rasm.